# Is it possible to transfer characters between Steam accounts?

Tags: payday-2

A little backstory, I am utilising the Steam Family Sharing functionality to essentially create a new Steam account with all of my current games on it. I have played Payday 2 extensively and reached level 100 with a whole variety of weapons, gadgets and stuff to blow people up. As a result of playing Payday 2 via the Steam Family Sharing functionality my character is not present - if I play using the original account it's all there and safe.

I copied the contents of Steam\userdata\profileID\218620 to the new profileID folder for the new account, however upon starting the game I get the following error:

[image]

Is it possible to transfer characters between Steam accounts so I can keep my character or am I going to have to start again?

Comment: There are save editors out there, for certain, but I don't know if they still work or not. Most of the websites that have download links for it are forums with "must register to see links" crap.

Comment: Apparently, savegames are also kept in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\PAYDAY 2\saves\seeminglyrandomnumber\ as well.

Comment: @Unionhawk Are there working save editors for the PC? All working save editors that I have been able to find are for consoles.

Comment: @galacticninja I don't know. I've been looking, but it doesn't look like it. There are a few that *promise* to work on PC, but totally fail to deliver on that.

Comment: I have a big feeling that OVERKILL will do a lot to prevent this from being a possibility as they have clearly stated they don't want people cheating their way up. The ability to do this would allow people to share savegames to get to level 100 immediately, which is the same as cheating.

Comment: @3ventic - How exactly is it cheating?  I don't disagree it shouldn't be allowed but for other reasons like, what is the point of even having levels, if everyone can just be level 100.  You can be level 100 but unless you have the money to purchase the skills its pointless.

Comment: @Ramhound saves also have your money and skills and a lot of other things.

Comment: @3ventic - I am well aware of that.  But you having money doesn't really effect you unless were talking about buying contracts, and I will be honest, my personal experience more people needed to buy contracts.  Overkill could very easily work around this Steam Feature but they have not, which tells a great deal, they likely don't want to bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there does not appear to be any way to transfer save data between Steam accounts, for good reason. Just search for "payday 2 save" on Google, and you'll see what I mean.

OVERKILL doesn't want people using pre-made or modified saves, and have thusly, made it very nearly impossible to modify them (though not *technically* impossible, since save data is stored on the client-side). It would appear that among the information that the save file stores, your SteamID is part of it, to keep people from using "LEVEL 100 ALL PERKS ALL MASKS ALL WEAPONS $1 BILLION CASH" save files off the internet.

Answer (score 1):

No, Steam Family Sharing is set up so that each account has their own cloud saves, achievements, etc.

For a game with transferable saves (e.g. Neverwinter Nights 2), you would have to manually copy the save files from one computer to the other.  Payday 2 locks your save to your steam profile, so short of a save game editor transferring saves will not work.